# Basic form and field state, infer paths in set/get

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to create a super simple form state api that we see everywhere.

And then I want to type the `setState` method and `getState` method.

For example doing this:

```
const api: TApi<{ email: string, password: string }> = ......;

// Should highlight saying this boolean is incorrect:
api.setState('fields.email.value', true);
```

These are my foundational types:

```
// Utils
type StringKeyOf<T> = Extract<keyof T, string>


// State
type TFieldState<T> = {
  value: T;
}
type TFormState<TValues extends Record<string, any>, TFieldName extends StringKeyOf<TValues>> = {
  submitting: boolean;
  fields: Record<TFieldName, TFieldState<TValues[TFieldName]>>
}
```

And here is my attempt to do the api:

```
type TApi<TValues extends Record<string, any>, TFieldName extends StringKeyOf<TValues>> = {
  setState<
    TBasePath extends StringKeyOf<TMyFormState>,
    TFieldPath extends `fields.${TFieldName}`,
    TFieldKeyPath extends `fields.${TFieldName}.${StringKeyOf<TFieldState<TValues[TFieldName]>>}`,
    TPath extends TBasePath | TFieldPath | TFieldKeyPath,
    TMyFormState = TFormState<TValues, TFieldName>,
  >(
    path: TPath,
    value: TPath extends TBasePath
            ? TMyState[TPath]
            : TPath extends `fields.${infer UFieldName}`
              ? TMyState['fields'][UFieldName]
              : TPath extends `fields.${infer UFieldName}.${infer UFieldKey}`
                ? TMyState['fields'][UFieldName][UFieldKey]
  ) => void
}
```

However this lights up like crazy. `TPath` should allow these paths:

```
type TPath = 
// Base Keys
| 'submitting'
| 'fields'

// Base fields
| 'fields.email'
| 'fields.password'

// Field keys
| 'fields.email.value'
| 'fields.password.value'
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEFUBcEsBsGcBQkCeAHApqAypATtAHYDmA0higPIBmAPACoB8oAvKAKIAe+AhgMaRaAawoB7aqHoAaUPHxFijRMpA5IPSBmTos9AGLQMsACa4NGBszYBvRKFAA3HrACuGAFySA3IgC+2zEk9UTwAWzNNBgA1Zzd4UAxuDEJjeIAlDD4Q41o5AhIZHkIURhl9QxMAOR5QrETNFPjcfLIKGmjYjHhGK1Bbe3gXACNQ6EgYEk8h0VFYDCKfe2oK1M8MrLwc8qNjatqygx2Ii3oY1y6AbW2qmowAXR6-FTAAQQAFAEllVED6F7RoB1zvF6slUqB1tlcvICqAiiUDis9nUko01C1yFQ6KdOt1ev1ZBhIMdaHZ7JIAEI8eAYN4aAAWCVR4OaCkx7XoAFkUMEwsdSmT7NdjHTIIzQWiAAbLHbwAB0ABJrMLkb5JVJBUEVpjReLmfFpSt5UqVbdfIrrKySOzsYcTCSccCrnbdrcHow1RryZJdUyGuD6FSab6AD5anah8MmHUMr3krk8kLhdSaVhBJMOs5xRE7ZEC+yMAAUmrQDM89F1cfsTnO5d9EoDQdpDM13u9AH5JNzecnzFddXdW237HWGX6wQaZSZjdYiNQMHgIC7VZKh8P7J2Ez3jhcAORT1K7u4XcDLt1r9ejsXjqUHmdzhdLpFmi0Pxen7UUNUX9egTfdjMUwwPc7yPE8z1qY8Px2TFB3sABKVhmAcURoGMJ5ECAA)

Anyne know how to do this, I think I'm super close.